# no matching function found to dnn_trainer in dlib

Tags: c++, deep-learning, dlib

I am trying to train the dlib'd deep learning model with my features set which is in csv. I imported the csv and converted the data into vectors of trainindata and traininglabels as

```
unsigned int col=22;
std::vector<std::vector<float> >trainingdata(10711,std::vector<float>(col));


for (int j=0; j<10712; j++) {
   std::vector<float> vt;
  // <vector<float> >vt;
   float tmp;
   for (int i = 0; i < 22; i++) {
       tmp=data[j][i];
      // cout<< tmp;
       vt.push_back(tmp);

   }
   trainingdata.push_back(vt);
}
std::vector<float> traininglabel;
for (int i=0;i<10712;i++) {
   float tmp = lastCol[i];
    traininglabel.push_back(tmp);
}
```

The data is converted into vectors successfully but I doubt it is not as per required format into dnn_trainer. The error is

```
error: no matching function for call to 'dlib::dnn_trainer<dlib::add_loss_layer<dlib::loss_multiclass_log_, dlib::add_layer<dlib::fc_<22ul, (dlib::fc_bias_mode)0u>, dlib::add_layer<dlib::relu_, dlib::add_layer<dlib::fc_<84ul, (dlib::fc_bias_mode)0u>, dlib::add_layer<dlib::relu_, dlib::add_layer<dlib::fc_<120ul, (dlib::fc_bias_mode)0u>, dlib::add_layer<dlib::max_pool_<2l, 2l, 2, 2, 0, 0>, dlib::add_layer<dlib::relu_, dlib::add_layer<dlib::con_<16l, 5l, 5l, 1, 1, 2, 2>, dlib::add_layer<dlib::max_pool_<2l, 2l, 2, 2, 0, 0>, dlib::add_layer<dlib::relu_, dlib::add_layer<dlib::con_<6l, 5l, 5l, 1, 1, 2, 2>, dlib::input<dlib::matrix<float> >, void>, void>, void>, void>, void>, void>, void>, void>, void>, void>, void> > >::train(std::vector<std::vector<float> >&, std::vector<float>&)'
     trainer.train( trainingdata,traininglabel);
```

the trainer.h file indicates that the input data should be of type

```
 void train (
        const std::vector<input_type>& data,
        const std::vector<training_label_type>& labels 
    )
```

I am following [this](http://dlib.net/dnn_introduction_ex.cpp.html) example with my dataset. Kindly help me out to resolve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I get an answer for this problem and that resolved it. The dlib dnn function takes the input as matrix vector and matrix is defined in dlib like MATLAB to boost the speed. SO teh input must have been defined as per that format. The csv loaded and passed to desired variables as:

```
std::vector<matrix<float> > trdata;
   std::vector<unsigned long>  trlabel;
   std::vector<matrix<float> > testdata;
    std::fstream file("features.csv");

    if (file.good()) {
        for(int row=0;row<10712; row++){
            for (int col = 0; col < 24; col++)
                        {
            string temp;
            if (col == 0)
                getline(file, temp,',');
            else if (col == 23)
            {
                getline(file, temp);
                trlabel[row]=stof(temp);
            }
            else
            {
                getline(file,temp , ',');
                trdata[row](0,0)=stof(temp);
            }

         }
    }

}
```

In it

```
std:vector<matrix<float> >trdata
```

is the way to define Testing input for training to DNN and

```
std::vector<unsigned long>trlabel
```

for the testing labels which must of unsigned long type